# Мониторинг изменений в базах данных

Tags: java

Нужен ваш совет.

Алгоритм определения изменений схемы данных.

**Введение:**
В крупной системе, реализующей микросервисную архитектуру часто возникает необходимость синхронизации горячих данных между различными компонентами (исполняемыми модулями). Как правило единой точкой правды для всех компонентов является СУБД, а именно какая либо схема или набор объектов СУБД. Но частые обращения к этим объектам, в особенности запросы содержащие агрегатные или аналитические функции, негативно влияют на производительность СУБД в целом. Поэтому для разных ситуаций разрабатывают различные тактики определения разности состояний тех или иных объектов СУБД для синхронизации с приложением.

**Что нужно сделать:**
Спроектировать алгоритм (функцию) определяющую есть ли изменения в СУБД или нет начиная с какого-либо времени или идентификатора.
Вариации:

- Вычисление изменение всей схемы целиком.
- Вычисление изменений заданных объектов (таблиц, колонок).
- Вычисление, реализованное только на JAVA без использования системных
  объектов СУБД.
- (повышенной сложности) Вычисление, реализованное только на SQL на
  СУБД Postgres.
- Вычисление допускает введение дополнительных сущностей в схему
  данных, либо рекомендации к проектированию схемы.

**Критерии оценки:**
Код должен быть покрыт нагрузочными тестами, приведены оценки планов запроса.

Написано относительно сложно, суть, как я понимаю, необходимо написать на java какую-нибудь простую реализацию: класс, который будет отслеживать изменения данных.

Я гуглил-гуглил и так и этак. Кто-то предлагает на основе анализа журнала транзакций, использовать механизм триггеров. Вроде бы в MS Sql Server и в postgresql есть какие-то встроенные инструменты для этого, кто то предлагал делать это посредством контрольных сумм, в то же время чего-то простого доступного мне найти не удалось. Может быть есть возможность подсказать?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding-explanation.html
Инфраструктура Logical Decoding.

Либо триггером пишете в pgq, ваше приложение вычитывает очередь pgq. Это сильно проще.